# Check if object has only the given keys using Lodash or Underscore

Tags: javascript, object, lodash, underscore.js

Is there a Lodash or Underscore method which can find if an object has only the given keys of that object. I would like a Lodash or Underscore implementation even though this sounds trivial using native JS.

For example if my object looks like and assuming there is a lodash method named `hasOnly`

```js
const obj = {
    name: undefined,
  age: 15,
  school: 'Some school'
}

_.hasOnly(obj,['name','age']) //return false

_.hasOnly(obj,['name','age','city']) //return false

_.hasOnly(obj,['name','age','school']) //return true
```

I couldn't seem to find a way in the docs

Comment: Side question, if it "sounds trivial using native JS" as you say yourself, why _require_ a library for it?

Comment: Do you want a native JS answer if one cannot be found in lodash/underscore docs?

Comment: @JeremyThille my project requires it since they are using it exclusively everywhere

Comment: So if your project required you to write a webserver, would you look for a method in lodash for that? Or, to put it another way if your woodworking project required you to bang in a nail, but you only had a wallpaper stripper, would you use that or look for a hammer?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to force use lodash/underscore when it can be easily done using native JS

Comment: i dont know maybe it is more readable and i'm a newcomer to the project. for example they use the lodash _.map as well instead of native map

Comment: But lodash `_.map` has some advantages/differences over native map. Have you asked/lloked into that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```js
hasOnly = (obj, props) => _.isEqual(_.keys(obj).sort(), props.sort())
```

The sorting is done because we are comparing arrays.

As an alternative, one could turn both `props` and `_.keys(obj)` into objects where the `props` and `_.keys(obj)` are the keys, whereas the value is a dummy one, always the same, such as `1`. The function to do so could be something like this:

```js
make1ValuedObj = keys => _.zipObject(keys, Array(keys.length).fill(1))
```

Then one would pass those to `_.isEqual` without having to sort anything:

```js
hasOnly = (obj, props) => _.isEqual(make1ValuedObj(_.keys(obj)), make1ValuedObj(props))
```

The reality is that a kind of "sorting" has to happen when you construct the objects, so I don't think there's a real advantage over the solution above.

Comment: I think that should be `_.zipObject` not `_.zipObj` - but its [getting slower](https://jsbench.me/r9kz2mwr9c/1)

Comment: @Jamiec, you're right. I picked a shorthand from [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide).

Comment: i wonder why they dont have an implementation for this. i thought there was only i couldn't find it. anyway thanks for the answers

Comment: @Jamiec, yes, it is slower. And it was still slow in the first place. I wander why. I'll probably ask a question myself for this specific use case (I've litterally rewritten your solution using lodash's equivalent of each of the memebr functions you used, and it's slow nonetheless; disappointing).

Comment: @Jamiec, [fwiw, fyi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70928926/why-is-lodash-slow).

Answer (score 2):

The native solution will be faster in almost all cases:

```js
const obj = {
  name: undefined,
  age: 15,
  school: 'Some school'
}

const hasOnly = (obj,props) => {
    var objProps = Object.keys(obj)
    return objProps.length == props.length && props.every(p => objProps.includes(p))
}

console.log(hasOnly(obj,['name','age'])) //return false

console.log(hasOnly(obj,['name','age','city'])) //return false

console.log(hasOnly(obj,['name','age','school'])) //return true
```

Benchmarking this against the other answer using lodash shows the lodash solution to be 95% slower (on my machine)

Benchmarks: https://jsbench.me/r9kz2mwr9c/1

Answer (score 1):

I think Enlico's answer is fine, but for completeness I'll mention another option which doesn't require sorting. This is based on comparing objects directy instead of comparing arrays of keys.

Note that the code below assumes the original Underscore. For Lodash, replace `_.mapObject` by `_.mapValues`.

```js
// replace all properties by true to prevent costly recursion
const mask = obj => _.mapObject(obj, _.constant(true));

function hasOnly(obj, keys) {
    const masked = mask(obj);
    // compare obj to a trimmed version of itself
    return _.isEqual(masked, _.pick(masked, keys));
}
```