# (Why) Is lodash slow?

Tags: javascript, performance, functional-programming, lodash

I was stunned by the reults described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70925552/5825294) and supported by [this](https://jsbench.me/r9kz2mwr9c/1) benchmark that compares that solution (native JavaScript) with [the one I proposed (Lodash)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70925457/5825294).

I've also compared the proposed solution:

```js
const obj = {
  name: undefined,
  age: 15,
  school: 'Some school'
}

const hasOnly = (obj,props) => {
    var objProps = Object.keys(obj)
    return objProps.length == props.length && props.every(p => objProps.includes(p))
}

console.log(hasOnly(obj,['name','age'])) //return false
console.log(hasOnly(obj,['name','age','city'])) //return false
console.log(hasOnly(obj,['name','age','school'])) //return true
```

with one where I truly simply switch from every native function to the corresponing function in Lodash,

```js
hasOnly = (obj,props) => {
    const objProps = _.keys(obj)
    return _.size(objProps) == _.size(props) && _.every(_.includes(objProps), props);
}
```

[and the result is still disappointly in favour of the native solution](https://jsbench.me/m3kz2v83ui/1).

Now, the one above might be a silly example, but still... > 90% slower? Then what am I using Lodash for? I mean, in different scenarios it can improve readability, expecially when funtions have to be partially applied and passed around, where Lodash saves you from a lot of `x => x.` (classic example `arrayOfarrays.map(_.map(fOnTheElements))` instead of `arrayOfarrays.map(arr => arr.map(fOnTheElements))`), but if the peformance is so low, then it's a bit hard to make the expressivity enough to choose Lodash over native code.

I'm new to JavaScript and Lodash (just not totally new to functional programming), so I don't even know the reliability of the benchmark tool that was used in the linked answer, but I can't believe it makes such a bad job that reverses the result.

Comment: What's wrong with question? :|

Comment: Why do you expect a library that uses native stuff to be faster than that native stuff? o.O

Comment: https://medium.com/techspiration/why-you-shouldnt-use-lodash-f8504d7b7383#:~:text=Performance&text=We%20can%20see%20that%20Lodash,take%20the%20small%20easy%20wins%3F

Comment: _"so I don't even know the reliability of the benchmark tool that was used in the linked answer"_ - Then why, based on that, are you making any assumptions?

Comment: @Andreas, I'm new to interpreted languages. I'm a C++ programmer, and the STL is fast. I mean, in general if `y` uses `native x`, `y` it's not necessarily slower than `native x`, I belive. It might be, just like it might not.

Comment: JavaScript is not C/C++...

Comment: @Andreas, yeah, that's the point. I don't know how it works, so I can't make the assumption that a level of indirection can be so disastrous. I can't even make the assumption that it is zero cost, sure. (By the way, I didn't expect it to be faster. Just not that slower.)

Comment: _"I don't know how it works"_ - Then stop making any assumptions... And most importantly stop using a library like Lodash if you're just starting with JavaScript.

Comment: @Andreas, I've asked a question because I'm _not_ making assumptions. I like the expressivity that Lodash offers in some contexts, and I'm just trying to understand if I should give up on that expressiveness because that library is too detrimental for the performance.

Comment: You have linked the same benchmark twice.  Did you mean to do that?

Comment: @Wyck, I don't remember anymore, but I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lodash is just javascript. There's no magic that can make it faster than the native code it is written in.

In short, every method call has an overhead. So if I do

```
const len = myArr.length
```

and you do

```
const len = _.size(myArr);
```

and we assume the implementation of `_.size` is

```
function size(arr){
    return arr.length
}
```

(It does more than that, but stay with me here!) Then at very least you have an extra method call that the native solution does not.

In actual fact `_.size` does *[even more than just check the length](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#size)*

> Gets the size of collection by returning its length for array-like values or the number of own enumerable string keyed properties for objects.

So on top of an extra method call you have the code for checking the "number of enumerable string keyed properties" - is it really any wonder that a native solution is quicker?

---

So why use a library like lodash? Because as their documentation headlines:

> Lodash makes JavaScript easier by taking the hassle out of working with arrays, numbers, objects, strings, etc.

So, you sacrifice a bit of speed for readability and ease of use.

Comment: _Then at very least you have an extra method call_. Wow, I would have never thought that the interpreter could not do any simplification/optimization on the code. I've implemented all the functions in my example as you've done for _.size, and I still get a run [~30% slower than native](https://jsbench.me/d7kz34a0q6/1). It's impressive :|

Comment: I don't think it's fair that you have the declaration of the functions as part of the test code. If you define the helper functions in Setup, you don't see any difference between the two: https://jsbench.me/k1kz8a82l3/1

Comment: @user3297291 You're absolutely right, that was a massive oversight. However you've somewhat changed the benchmark there by making the logash versions not call `_.size` (and the ther lodash functions in the original). If I keep the intention of testing lodash vs native but move the function setups outside the benchmarks you still do in fact get the same result. https://jsbench.me/r9kz2mwr9c/2

Comment: Was mostly commenting on the 30% slower claim by @Enlico  Good to see your updated version with the actual lodash reference though!